# Remove routing from destroyed controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have generated a controller in Rails 3 and then destroyed it with:

```
rails destroy controller MyController
```

This does not seem to have removed MyController from the routing, there are still references to MyController and its methods when I run

```
rake routes
```

How do I remove the routing for the now destroyed MyController? Shouldn't the destroy command do this cleanup?

Sorry if this is a basic question, I am a Rails rookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the routes that refer to `MyController` from the `config/routes.rb` file.